# How to load an index.js file in a plugin system?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, electron

I have a lonely index.js file stored like this:
plugins/some_plugin/index.js

When I run require(path_to_index.js) in my app, I get a 'cannot find modules' error.

This makes sense of course because there is no node_modules folder in the "some_plugin" folder.

So how do I load this index.js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with NodeJS, when you want to require a module, you should make it in this form:

```
module.exports = {
    data: 'some_data',
    function: ()=>console.log("it works");
};
```

If you build your module that way, there shouldn't be any problem to include it just by doing:

```
let module = require('./plugins/some_plugin/index.js');
```

Just tested it and it worked for me. Hope it can help you.